psycopg2 and PostgreSQL --- FATAL: password authentication failed for user "xyz"
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "xyz"
I have changed contents of /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf file many times and still can't figure out the problem. I am using psycopg2 version 2.9.9 and PostgreSQL on WSL 2 Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Main objective is to have successful security-enhanced connection to my psql db using environment variable authentication. Environment variables are properly exported into WSL 2 from host Windows OS. Side note, the password for xyz user contains '-'. Not sure if special characters can cause problems. User xyz has superuser privileges as well.
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
params = {
    'dbname': os.getenv('DB_NAME', config.get('database', 
    'dbname')),
    'user': os.getenv('DB_USER', config.get('database', 
    'user')),
    'password': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', config.get('database', 
    'password')),
    'host': os.getenv('DB_HOST', config.get('database', 
    'host')),
    'port': os.getenv('DB_PORT', config.get('database', 'port')) 
}


To question add as text: 1) The contents of pg_hba.conf. 2) The Postgres version. 3) Whether you restored the data from another instance of Postgres and if so what version that instance is. 4) Any relevant errors in the Postgres log from when the connection was attempted.

@AdrianKlaver You're a genius my guy. I'm new to this so I checked the psql log for the first time and found that no password was assigned to the user xyz. I set the password equivalent to the environment variable, and it connected successfully. Thank you for your help!
